# wget bash script with variable into link

Tags: bash, shell, wget

is it possible if i want to download file from website and i want to download file only the file that was uploaded in ten days a go. there is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define a julian days function
DATE (){
  date -d 'now - 10 days' +"%j"
}

wget -o downloadNew.log --user=xxxx --password=yyyy -r -c -nH -nd -np -N -A '*.nc'  --content-disposition 'https://tropomi.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/S5P_TROPOMI_Level2/S5P_L2__NO2____HiR.1/2020/'$DATE
```

when i run this code that is download all of data in https://tropomi.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/S5P_TROPOMI_Level2/S5P_L2__NO2____HiR.1/2020/
i just want the data in ten days a go not all data in 2020 years .

Comment: Trying putting the URL in double quotes to expand $DATE.

Comment: I have tried this but the results are still the same

Comment: `wget -o downloadNew.log --user=xxxx --password=yyyy -r -c -nH -nd -np -N -A '*.nc'  --content-disposition 'https://tropomi.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/S5P_TROPOMI_Level2/S5P_L2__NO2____HiR.1/2020/'"$DATE" `

Comment: I meant putting the whole url starting with http in double quotes instead of single quotes

Comment: i also try that but nothing change at all.

Comment: BTW when specifying the date string to the `-d` option, do not put a whitespace
after the minus `-` sign. Please say `"-10 days"` or `"10 days ago"` instead.

Comment: i see the problem. i am forget to add () to the `"$DATE"`.So the code must be
```wget -o downloadNew.log --user=xxxx --password=yyyy -r -c -nH -nd -np -N -A '*.nc'  --content-disposition 'https://tropomi.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/S5P_TROPOMI_Level2/S5P_L2__NO2____HiR.1/2020/'"$(DATE)"```
  Thanks .